# PyGame удаление созданной фигуры

Tags: python, pygame

хочу сделать при клике на кружочек он исчезал но не исчезает.

```
import pygame
from random import randint

WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 30

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

def main():
    circles = []
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Training Reaction")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    click_rect = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//3, HEIGHT//3, WIDTH//3, HEIGHT//3)
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.mouse.set_cursor(pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_ARROW)
    screen.lock()
    for x in range(0, 10):
        randomX = randint(50, WIDTH-50)
        randomY = randint(50, HEIGHT-50)
        circles.append(pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (randomX, randomY), 15))
        pygame.display.update()
    screen.unlock()
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if click_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    for x in circles:
                        circles.remove(x)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Смотри тут <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773684/detect-mouse-click-on-circle-that-is-on-different-surface>

Comment: Ничего не понятно.